# LINQ in Razor function

Tags: c#, linq, razor, file-upload

I might be going about this the wrong way, but i am trying to insert strings into my Razor syntax.

My list looks like this:

```
 public List<string> listOfLimitedFileTypes { get; set; }
```

The list is comprised of "image/png", "image/jpeg", "application/pdf",etc.

On my razor (C#) page, i would like to do something like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) Model.form.fields(i).uploadfile, New With {.type = "file", .accept = Model.form.fields(i).listOfLimitedFileTypes.ToString() })
```

and have my HTML compile to something like this:

```
<input accept="image/png, image/jpeg, application/pdf" id="form_fields_0__uploadfile" name="form.fields[0].uploadfile" type="file" value="">
```

I do know of other ways of doing this if the Model, but i am just curious if something like this is possible with LINQ or if i can do a `for each` inside the razor function.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I would like the list of strings to be concatenated together, with commas perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use method called [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) Model.form.fields(i).uploadfile, New With {.type = "file", .accept = string.Join(", ",Model.form.fields(i).listOfLimitedFileTypes) })
```

Sorry there can be syntax error as I am not vb guy but my point is to use string.Join method

Comment: Thanks! I will try it tomorrow. I didn't even think of join().

Comment: @MaylorTaylor You can play with string.Join here on plunker with `C#`. https://dotnetfiddle.net/0c00GN